# function does not store data to struct array

Tags: c++

I have a function with is suppose to calculate an employees time based of employee type, and hours worked. If management straight pay no matter the hours, if union overtime pay.

I have two struct arrays, one for employee data and then one for their timesheet.
The problem Im having is I dont think my function is storing the calculated data. As when I run my print out function I get zeros.

Ive been stuck on this for a bit, I have tried to debug my code the best I could but Im not getting anything and it compiles no issues.

what is my issue? or issues?

**C++**

```
//*********************************************************************************************
//         Structure to hold employee ID, Name, Pay rate per hour, Employee type
//*********************************************************************************************

struct employeeRecord {
    int IDnum;    // holds employee id number
    string name;    // holds employess name
    float payRate;    // holds employee pay rate
    int empType;    // holds employee type
};

//*********************************************************************************************
//                         structure to hold time sheet
//*********************************************************************************************

struct timeSheet{
    float hoursWorked;    //hours worked
    float grossPay;    // gross pay
    float netPay;    // net pay
    float taxAmount;    // tax amount deduction
};

//*********************************************************************************************
//                               function prototype
//*********************************************************************************************
void addEmployee(employeeRecord *employee, int &index);
void addTime(timeSheet *time, employeeRecord *employee, int &index);
void calcTime(timeSheet *time, employeeRecord *employee, int &index, float taxRate);
void outTime(timeSheet *time, employeeRecord *employee, int &index);

//*********************************************************************************************
//                                 main function
//*********************************************************************************************

int main(){


    float taxRate = .15;    // taxrate on pay
    char choice;    // holds user choice option
    int index = 0; // index of array

    // create struct arrays to hold data
    employeeRecord employee[2];
    timeSheet time[2];
//*********************************************************************************************
//                      ^^^^^^not my entire main function^^^^^Can post if needed^^^^^^
//*********************************************************************************************

/*********************************************************************************************
//                    function to to calculate timesheet
//*********************************************************************************************

void calcTime(timeSheet *time, employeeRecord *employee, int &index, float taxRate){
    index = 0;    // set index back to zero to start at first array index
    float tempHours;    //temp hour hold
    float overTime;    // overTime hours
    float hoursWorked = time[index].hoursWorked;    //hours worked 
    float grossPay = time[index].grossPay;    //employes's gross pay
    float netPay = time[index].netPay;    //employes's net pay
    float taxAmount = time[index].taxAmount;    ////employes's tax deduction
    int empType = employee[index].empType;    // employee type
    float payRate = employee[index].payRate;    // employes pay rate

    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++){
        if (empType == 0){
            if(hours > 40){
                tempHours = 40;
                overTime = hoursWorked - 40;
                grossPay = (overTime * (payRate * 1.5)) + (tempHours * payRate);
                taxAmount = grossPay * taxRate;
                netPay = grossPay - taxAmount;
            }
            else{
                grossPay = hoursWorked * payRate;
                taxAmount = grossPay * taxRate;
                netPay = grossPay - taxAmount;
            }
        }
        else{
            grossPay = hoursWorked * payRate;
            taxAmount = grossPay * taxRate;
            netPay = grossPay - taxAmount;
        }

        // increase index number
        index++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Put remarks into comments as well, just in case anybody wants to run your code. You don't want to burden anyone with tedious code formatting, do you? And **do not define functions within functions**.

Comment: Actually, I don't think waterrunner4 necessarily defined functions within functions, I think it was just rushed copy pasting.

Comment: That was a format issue, I fixed it I believe. what do you mean put remarks in comments as well.. I think I may have fixed that. I didnt post all my code cause I had a previous issue and got griped at for that, thats why my main function I just posted enough to show my struc arrays

Comment: In the spirit of "teaching to fish" may I suggest you turn on all compiler warnings (`-Wall -Werror` for gcc and clang) and you should get some comments about overwriting `netPay` but never reading it.

Comment: @sam do you know by chance if Im using dev c++ on windows how would i go about turning such warnings on?

Comment: @waterunnr4, sorry, I do not. MS compiler are very smart. They should have a great feature set and some Googling may tease it out. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In calc time, you only store things in local variables.

```
    float hoursWorked = time[index].hoursWorked;    //hours worked
```

This creates a local variable called `hoursWorked` which goes away when it goes out of scope, it does not create a short-cut reference to `time[index].hoursWorked`. All the work you are doing is occurring in these temporary locals and not affecting time or employee at all.

If you changed this to be:

```
    float& hoursWorked = time[index].hoursWorked;    //hours worked
```

this makes `hoursWorked` a reference, or alias, for `time[index].hoursWorked`, so any changes you make to it actually change `time[index].hoursWorked`.

This should make the code work as expected.

Comment: thank you!! this worked, I wasn't even thinking about it storing only in local variables and that being the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your function headers to pass your structures as array pointers?

```
void addTime(timeSheet *time[], employeeRecord *employee[], int &index){
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `calcTime()` only writes to local values which are *copies* of those values in the struct. If you wanted to operate on the stored value you should use a reference:

```
// Assignments to netPay will modify timesheet[i]
float& netPay = timesheet[i].netPay

// netPay is a copy.
float netPay = timesheet[i].netPay
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have your foundation in place, let's improve on what you already have. I am going to rename your structure `employeeRecord` to `EmployeeInfo` and you will see why I do this.

`stdafx.h` should have at least iostream, string, and memory, and any other std library containers, methods and algorithms you need included.

**EmployeeRecord.h**

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_RECORD_H
#define EMPLOYEE_RECORD_H

struct EmployeeInfo {
    std::string name;
    unsigned    ID;
    unsigned    type;
    float       payRate;
}; // EmployeeInfo

struct TimeSheet {
    float hoursWorked;
    float grossPay;
    float netPay;
    float taxAmount;
}; // TimeSheet

class EmployeeRecord {
public:
    static const float m_fTaxRate;
    static const float m_fFullTimeHours;
    static const float m_fOverTimeRate;

    enum EmployeeType {
        ET_MANAGEMENT = 1,
        ET_UNION,
    }; // EmployeeType

private:
    std::shared_ptr<EmployeeInfo> m_pEmployeeInfo;
    std::shared_ptr<TimeSheet>    m_pTimeSheet;

public:
    EmployeeRecord();
    explicit EmployeeRecord( const std::string& strName );
    EmployeeRecord( const std::string& strName, const unsigned id );
    EmployeeRecord( const std::string& strName, const unsigned id, const EmployeeType type );
    EmployeeRecord( const std::string& strName, const unsigned id, const EmployeeType type, const float payRate );
    EmployeeRecord( const std::string& strName, const unsigned id, const EmployeeType type, const float payRate, const float hoursWorked );

    EmployeeRecord(const std::string& strName, const unsigned id, const unsigned type);
    EmployeeRecord(const std::string& strName, const unsigned id, const unsigned type, const float payRate);
    EmployeeRecord(const std::string& strName, const unsigned id, const unsigned type, const float payRate, const float hoursWorked);

    explicit EmployeeRecord( const EmployeeInfo& info );
    EmployeeRecord( const EmployeeInfo&, const float hours );

    ~EmployeeRecord();

    // To set Individual Parameters To The Employee Info Struct
    void setName( const std::string& strName );
    void setId( const unsigned id );
    void setType( const EmployeeType type );
    void setType( const unsigned type );
    void setPayRate( const float rate );

    // To Set A Fully Predefined EmployeeInfo
    void setEmployeeInfo( const EmployeeInfo& info );

    // To Retrieve Individual Parameters From EmpolyeeInfo
    std::string     getName() const;
    unsigned        getId() const;
    float           getPayRate() const;
    EmployeeType    getEmployeeType() const;
    unsigned        getEmployeeUType() const;

    // To Retrieve An Entire EmployeeInfo
    EmployeeInfo    getEmployeeInfo() const;

    // To Add Individual Parameters To The TimeSheet Struct
    void setHoursWorked( const float hours );

    // Calculate Values In Time Sheet
    void calculateWages();

    // To Get Individual Parameters From Time Sheet
    float getHoursWorked() const;
    float getGrossPay() const;
    float getNetPay() const;
    float getTaxAmount() const;

    // Retrieve An Entire Employee TimeSheet
    TimeSheet getTimeSheet() const;

}; // EmployeeRecord

#endif // EMPLOYEE_RECORD_H
```

**EmployeeRecord.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "EmployeeRecord.h"

const float EmployeeRecord::m_fTaxRate = 0.15f;
const float EmployeeRecord::m_fFullTimeHours = 40.0f;
const float EmployeeRecord::m_fOverTimeRate = 1.5f;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord() :
m_pEmployeeInfo( nullptr ),
m_pTimeSheet( nullptr ),
m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled( false ) {
    m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>();
    // m_pEmployeeInfo.reset( new EmployeeInfo );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->name    = std::string();
    m_pEmployeeInfo->ID      = 0;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->type    = 0;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate = 0.0f;

    m_pTimeSheet = std::make_shared<TimeSheet>();
    //m_pTimeSheet.reset( new TimeSheet );
    m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked  = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->grossPay     = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->netPay       = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount    = 0.0f;

} // EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord( const std::string& name ) :
m_pEmployeeInfo( nullptr ),
m_pTimeSheet( nullptr ),
m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled( false ) {
    // EmployeeInfo
    m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>();
    //m_pEmployeeInfo.reset( new EmployeeInfo );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->name     = name;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->ID       = 0;  
    m_pEmployeeInfo->type     = 0;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate  = 0.0f;

    // TimeSheet
    m_pTimeSheet = std::make_shared<TimeSheet>();
    //m_pTimeSheet.reset( new TimeSheet );
    m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->grossPay    = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->netPay      = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount   = 0.0f;
} // EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord( const std::string& name, const unsigned id ) :
m_pEmployeeInfo( nullptr ),
m_pTimeSheet( nullptr ),
m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled( false ) {
    // EmployeeInfo
    m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>();
    //m_pEmployeeInfo.reset( new EmployeeInfo );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->name    = name;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->ID      = id;  
    m_pEmployeeInfo->type    = 0;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate = 0.0f;

    // TimeSheet
    m_pTimeSheet = std::make_shared<TimeSheet>();
    //m_pTimeSheet.reset(new TimeSheet);
    m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->grossPay    = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->netPay      = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount   = 0.0f;
} // EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord( const std::string& name, const unsigned id, const EmployeeType type ) :
m_pEmployeeInfo( nullptr ),
m_pTimeSheet( nullptr ),
m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled( false ) {
    // EmployeeInfo
    m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>();
    //m_pEmployeeInfo.reset( new EmployeeInfo );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->name    = name;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->ID      = id;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->type    = static_cast<unsigned>( type );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate = 0.0f;

    // TimeSheet
    m_pTimeSheet = std::make_shared<TimeSheet>();
    //m_pTimeSheet.reset(new TimeSheet);
    m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->grossPay    = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->netPay      = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount   = 0.0f;
} // EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord( const std::string& name, const unsigned id, const EmployeeType type, float rate ) :
m_pEmployeeInfo( nullptr ),
m_pTimeSheet( nullptr ),
m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled( false ) {
    // EmployeeRecord
    m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>();
    //m_pEmployeeInfo.reset( new EmployeeInfo );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->name    = name;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->ID      = id;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->type    = static_cast<unsigned>( type );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate = rate;

    // TimeSheet
    m_pTimeSheet = std::make_shared<TimeSheet>();
    // m_pTimeSheet.reset( new TimeSheet );
    m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->grossPay    = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->netPay      = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount   = 0.0f;
} // EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord(const std::string& name, const unsigned id, const EmployeeType type, const float rate, const float hours) :
m_pEmployeeInfo( nullptr ),
m_pTimeSheet( nullptr ),
m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled( false ) {
    // EmployeeInfo 
    m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>();
    // m_pEmployeeInfo.reset( new EmployeeInfo );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->name    = name;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->ID      = id;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->type    = static_cast<unsigned>( type );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate = rate;

    // TimeSheet
    m_pTimeSheet = std::make_shared<TimeSheet>();
    // m_pTimeSheet.reset( new TimeSheet );
    m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = hours;
    m_pTimeSheet->grossPay    = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->netPay      = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount   = 0.0f;

    // Since We Have Enough Data Calculate Wages & Taxes Here
    calculateWages();
} // EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord(const std::string& name, const unsigned id, const unsigned type) :
m_pEmployeeInfo( nullptr ),
m_pTimeSheet( nullptr ),
m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled( false ) {
    // EmployeeInfo
    m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>();
    //m_pEmployeeInfo.reset( new EmployeeInfo );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->name = name;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->ID = id;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->type = type;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate = 0.0f;

    // TimeSheet
    m_pTimeSheet = std::make_shared<TimeSheet>();
    //m_pTimeSheet.reset(new TimeSheet);
    m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->grossPay = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->netPay = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount = 0.0f;
} // EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord(const std::string& name, const unsigned id, const unsigned type, float rate) :
m_pEmployeeInfo( nullptr ),
m_pTimeSheet( nullptr ),
m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled( false ) {
    // EmployeeRecord
    m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>();
    //m_pEmployeeInfo.reset( new EmployeeInfo );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->name = name;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->ID = id;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->type = type;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate = rate;

    // TimeSheet
    m_pTimeSheet = std::make_shared<TimeSheet>();
    // m_pTimeSheet.reset( new TimeSheet );
    m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->grossPay = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->netPay = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount = 0.0f;
} // EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord(const std::string& name, const unsigned id, const unsigned type, const float rate, const float hours) :
m_pEmployeeInfo( nullptr ),
m_pTimeSheet( nullptr ),
m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled( false ) {
    // EmployeeInfo 
    m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>();
    // m_pEmployeeInfo.reset( new EmployeeInfo );
    m_pEmployeeInfo->name = name;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->ID = id;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->type = type;
    m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate = rate;

    // TimeSheet
    m_pTimeSheet = std::make_shared<TimeSheet>();
    // m_pTimeSheet.reset( new TimeSheet );
    m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = hours;
    m_pTimeSheet->grossPay = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->netPay = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount = 0.0f;

    // Since We Have Enough Data Calculate Wages & Taxes Here
    calculateWages();
} // EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord( const EmployeeInfo& info ) :
m_pEmployeeInfo( nullptr ),
m_pTimeSheet( nullptr ),
m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled( false ) {
    // EmployeeInfo
    m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>( info );

    // TimeSheet
    m_pTimeSheet = std::make_shared<TimeSheet>();
    //m_pTimeSheet.reset( new TimeSheet );
    m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->grossPay    = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->netPay      = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount   = 0.0f;
} // EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord( const EmployeeInfo& info, const float hours ) :
m_pEmployeeInfo( nullptr ),
m_pTimeSheet( nullptr ),
m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled( false ) {
    // EmployeeInfo
    m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>( info );

    // TimeSheet
    m_pTimeSheet = std::make_shared<TimeSheet>();
    // m_pTimeSheet.reset( new TimeSheet );
    m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = hours;
    m_pTimeSheet->grossPay = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->netPay = 0.0f;
    m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount = 0.0f;

    // Since We Have Enough Data Calculate Wages & Taxes Here
    calculateWages();
} // EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ~EmployeeRecord()
EmployeeRecord::~EmployeeRecord() {
    m_pEmployeeInfo.reset();
    m_pEmployeeInfo = nullptr;
    m_pTimeSheet.reset();
    m_pTimeSheet = nullptr;
} // ~EmployeeRecord

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setName()
void EmployeeRecord::setName( const std::string& name ) {
    m_pEmployeeInfo->name = name;
} // setName

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setId()
void EmployeeRecord::setId( unsigned id ) {
    m_pEmployeeInfo->ID = id;
} // setId

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setType()
void EmployeeRecord::setType( const EmployeeType type ) {
    if ( m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled ) {
        if ( m_pEmployeeInfo->type != static_cast<unsigned>( type ) ) { 
            m_pEmployeeInfo->type = static_cast<unsigned>( type );
            calculateWages();
        }
    } else {
        m_pEmployeeInfo->type = static_cast<unsigned>( type );
    }
} // setType

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setType()
void EmployeeRecord::setType( const unsigned type ) {
    if ( m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled ) {
        if ( m_pEmployeeInfo->type != type ) {
            m_pEmployeeInfo->type = type;
            calculateWages();
        }
    } else {
        m_pEmployeeInfo->type = type;
    }
} // setType

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setPayRate()
void EmployeeRecord::setPayRate( const float rate ) {
    if ( m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled ) {
        if ( m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate != rate ) {
            m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate = rate;
            calculateWages();
        }
    } else {
        m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate = rate;
    }
} // setPayRate

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setEmployeeInfo()
void EmployeeRecord::setEmployeeInfo( const EmployeeInfo& info ) {
    if ( nullptr == m_pEmployeeInfo ) {
        m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>( info );
    } else {
        m_pEmployeeInfo.reset();
        m_pEmployeeInfo = std::make_shared<EmployeeInfo>( info );
    }
} // setEmployeeInfo

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getName()
std::string EmployeeRecord::getName() const {
    return m_pEmployeeInfo->name;
} // getName

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getId()
unsigned EmployeeRecord::getId() const {
    return m_pEmployeeInfo->ID;
} // getId

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getPayRate()
float EmployeeRecord::getPayRate() const {
    return m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate;
} // getPayRate

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getEmployeeType()
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeType EmployeeRecord::getEmployeeType() const {
    return static_cast<EmployeeType>( m_pEmployeeInfo->type );
} // getEmployeeType

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getEmployeeUType()
unsigned EmployeeRecord::getEmployeeUType() const {
    return m_pEmployeeInfo->type;
} // getEmployeeUType

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getEmployeeInfo
EmployeeInfo EmployeeRecord::getEmployeeInfo() const {
    return *m_pEmployeeInfo.get();
} // getEmployeeInfo

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setHoursWorked()
void EmployeeRecord::setHoursWorked( const float hours ) {
    if ( m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled ) {
        if ( m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked != hours ) {
            m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = hours;
            calculateWages();
        }
    } else {
        m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked = hours;
    }
} // setHoursWorked

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// calculateWages()
void EmployeeRecord::calculateWages() {
    // Error Cases
    if ( m_pEmployeeInfo == nullptr ) {
        std::cout << "Error: m_pEmployeeInfo = nullptr; not enough information to calculate wages and taxes." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if ( m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate == 0.0f ) {
        std::cout << "Error: payRate = " << m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate << " can not caculate wages and taxes." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if ( m_pEmployeeInfo->type == 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Error: EmployeeType = " << m_pEmployeeInfo->type << " can not determine which pay scale to use." << std::endl;
        return;
    }   

    // Warning Cases
    if ( m_pEmployeeInfo->name.empty() ) {
        std::cout << "Warning: It is possible to calculate wages and taxes, but no name available to assign it to." << std::endl;
    }

    if ( m_pEmployeeInfo->ID == 0 || m_pEmployeeInfo->ID == -1 ) {
        std::cout << "Warning: It is possible to calculate wages and taxes, but current employeeID is invalid." << std::endl;
    }

    if ( m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked == 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Warning: hours worked = " << m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked << " it is possible that this employee worked 0 hours." << std::endl;
    }

    switch ( static_cast<EmployeeType>( m_pEmployeeInfo->type ) ) {
        case ET_MANAGEMENT: {
            m_pTimeSheet->grossPay  = m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate * m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked;
            m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount = m_pTimeSheet->grossPay * m_fTaxRate;
            m_pTimeSheet->netPay    = m_pTimeSheet->grossPay - m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount;
            break;
        }
        case ET_UNION: {
            float overTimeHours = 0.0f;
            if ( m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked > m_fFullTimeHours ) {
                overTimeHours = m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked - m_fFullTimeHours;
            }

            m_pTimeSheet->grossPay  = (m_pEmployeeInfo->payRate * m_fFullTimeHours) + (overTimeHours * m_fOverTimeRate);
            m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount = m_pTimeSheet->grossPay * m_fTaxRate;
            m_pTimeSheet->netPay    = m_pTimeSheet->grossPay - m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount;
            break;
        }
    }

    m_bCalcWagesHasBeenCalled = true;
} // calculateWages

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getHoursWorked()
float EmployeeRecord::getHoursWorked() const {
    return m_pTimeSheet->hoursWorked;
} // getHoursWorked

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getGrossPay()
float EmployeeRecord::getGrossPay() const {
    return m_pTimeSheet->grossPay;
} // getGrossPay

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getNetPay()
float EmployeeRecord::getNetPay() const {
    return m_pTimeSheet->netPay;
} // getNetPay

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getTaxAmount()
float EmployeeRecord::getTaxAmount() const {
    return m_pTimeSheet->taxAmount;
} // getTaxAmount

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getTimeSheet()
TimeSheet EmployeeRecord::getTimeSheet() const {
    return *m_pTimeSheet.get();
} // getTimeSheet
```

This class has several constructors: one is default which will create an empty instance that needs to be filled out later by either passing in individual fields or by passing in the required structures. It has partial constructors where the rest will have to be filled out later. It has a couple of full constructors that if successfully constructed, they will automatically call the method to calculate both wages and taxes. The are a few setting functions that will check to see if `calculateWages()` has already been called and if there is a difference in value being passed, if both cases are true then it will update that field and call `calculateWages()` again, if not it will just add the value.